# Initializing bootsrap datatimepicker on server side in asp.net webforms

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, webforms, pageload

I have got this **HTML**

```
<div class='datepicker input-group date' id='datetimepickerStart'>
  <input type='text' class="form-control" />
  <span class="input-group-addon">
     <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
  </span>
</div>
```

and this **JS**

```
$(function () {
    $('.datepicker').datetimepicker({
        locale: 'es',
        maxDate: 'now',
        format: 'DD/MM/YYYY'
    });
});
```

I would like to initialize `datepicker` using `Page_Load` event.

Is it possible to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have to use

```
  <input type='text' class="form-control" runat="server" id="DateStart" />
```

and in the `Page_Load` event

```
 DateStart.Value = DateTime.Now.ToString();
```